# Neo4j filter nodes by summation of specific parameter

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j

I need cypher query to filter nodes according to summation of specific parameters

For example:
I have some employees who work in a company with different salaries

[See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9WvV.png)

I need to get employees who their total salaries is less than 15000, the result

[See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovi80.png)

any good ideas for this

Comment: and how is your data model in neo4j ?

Comment: I have a normal data model for a company which contain employees, departments ... etc. I have tried a lot of cypher queries like MATCH (employee:Employee) WITH employee, SUM(employee.salary) as salary WHERE salary > 5000 RETURN employee